# QGIS crashes and closes after running a Python script for the second time

Tags: pyqgis

My goal is to use a Python script to generate ranges for the graduated symbol renderer. I want to compare datasets, in this case the amount of simulated recharge to a groundwater aquifer, over time and I want to set the ranges to be consistent over those years. It's a pain to type all of those in - a task tailor made for scripting.

The following script works... once. It gives me the ranges and labels I specify. I also had more code that dealt with the symbols to make it prettier, but in trying to debug this, I've tried to whittle this down to the bare minimum.

So in summary, the code runs once without incident. If I try to run it again, the PC (or Mac - I have replicated this behavior with different QGIS projects on PC and Mac) thinks for a few seconds (like 3) then crashes. On PC, the QGIS window vanishes and there's no message. On mac, there's a crash log that is supposedly sent to Apple (haven't heard from them yet... ha)

If you want to replicate my alleged issue, I think all you'd have to do is have a point layer active and change the value it line 2 "myTargetField" to some numeric attribute in your point layer.

Here's the code:

```
myVectorLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
myTargetField = '2011'
myRangeList = []
r = None
stepSz = .1
myMin = myMax = 0

# loop to make ranges
for r in range(0,40,2):
    myMin = .1 * r
    myMax = .1 * r + stepSz
    myLabel = f'{myMin:.1f}-{myMax:.1f}'
    mySymbol1 = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
    myRange1 = QgsRendererRange(myMin, myMax, mySymbol1, myLabel)

    myRangeList.append(myRange1)
#    print(f'min: {myMin}  max: {myMax}')
myMin = myMax
myMax = 12
myLabel = f'{myMin:.1f}-{myMax:.1f}' 
myRange1 = QgsRendererRange(myMin, myMax, mySymbol1, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange1)
myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(myTargetField)
myVectorLayer.setRenderer(myRenderer)
del myVectorLayer
```

Any insights?

Comment: does it work if you remove the last line?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Yes, it works with or without the last line. I added the last line thinking maybe it would clear up some memory issue. It didn't make any difference, but I just left that line there.

Comment: I'd suggest raising a bug against QGIS. I can replicate it on QGIS 3.34 on Windows.